# How to combine (or merge) multiple complex Lists and convert to a string array with separator ; in C#

Tags: c#

I am facing a performance challenge when try to combine or merge multiple lists by using for loop to return a string array with a designated separator ;
The sample of class and data structure shows as below.

I think it is possible to use LINQ but I have no idea how to do so.
Please kindly instruct me how to implement by using LINQ.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class DataGroup
    {
        private string _Name;
        private List<double> _ValueList;

        public DataGroup(string Name, List<double> ValueList)
        {
            _Name = Name;
            _ValueList = ValueList;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            set { _Name = value; }
            get { return (_Name); }

        }
        public List<double> ValueList
        {
            set { _ValueList = value; }
            get { return (_ValueList); }
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Assume the element count of Log time will be ALWAYS same as the values of each DataGroup.
            //Sample data for test
            List<DateTime> LogTime = new List<DateTime>()
            { 
                new DateTime (2022,5,31,14,4,0), new DateTime (2022,5,31,14,4,10), new DateTime (2022,5,31,14,4,20) 
            };


            List<DataGroup> ALLData = new List<DataGroup>();

            ALLData.Add(new DataGroup("V1", new List<double>() { 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 }));
            ALLData.Add(new DataGroup("V2", new List<double>() { 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 }));
            ALLData.Add(new DataGroup("V3", new List<double>() { 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 }));
            ALLData.Add(new DataGroup("V4", new List<double>() { 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 }));
            ALLData.Add(new DataGroup("V5", new List<double>() { 5.1, 5.2, 5.3 }));

            List<string> DataRows = new List<string>();

            string[] logtimeLsit = LogTime.Select(LT => LT.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff")).ToArray();
            double [] ValueList = ALLData.SelectMany(AD=>AD.ValueList).ToArray();

            string Header = "LogTime;" + String.Join(";", ALLData.Select(AD => AD.Name).ToArray());

            int TotalRowCount=LogTime.Count;

            int TotalValueCountinEachSensor=ALLData.Count;

            DataRows.Add(Header);

            for (int Pos = 0; Pos < TotalRowCount; Pos++)
            {
                string DataRow = logtimeLsit[Pos] + ";";

                for (int inPos = 0; inPos < TotalValueCountinEachSensor; inPos++)
                {
                    int offsetPos =Pos+( inPos * TotalRowCount);
                    DataRow += ValueList[offsetPos] + ";";
                }
                DataRows.Add(DataRow.Remove(DataRow.Length - 1, 1));
            }

            Console.Write(DataRows.ToArray());
            // ToDO: Output a string array like 
            //  string [] dataRows = {
            //                          "LogTime;V1;V2;V3;V4;V5",
            //                          "2022/05/31 14:04:00;1.1;2.1;3.1;3.1;5.1",
            //                          "2022/05/31 14:04:10;1.2;2.2;3.2;3.2;5.2",
            //                          "2022/05/31 14:04:20;1.3;2.3;3.3;3.3;5.3",
            //                       };     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, can you fix it first? Secondly, you say you have a performance problem - so you have a solution that works? Can you show it? Next, how many items are going to be in each list? And finally, what happens if there is a mismatch in the number of items in the first and second lists?

Comment: And what makes you think that LINQ will solve your performance problem?

Comment: Hi, 
first of all, thank you for the response.
I apologize for not posting the correct sample code. please refer to the code that works.  
Regarding your questions: 
1) The item count of data group will be less than 250, however, the number of value list in each data group may have up to 60K. 
2) The mismatched issue for the numbers of value list in each data group can be ignored. 
3) LINQ may be able to handle it better I think so I would like to try if there is any better approach to make it work faster.

Hopefully my response meets your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
string[] dataRows =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, LogTime.Count)
        .Select(n => String.Join(";", ALLData.Select(x => x.ValueList[n].ToString()).Prepend(LogTime[n].ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))))
        .StartWith(String.Join(";", ALLData.Select(x => x.Name).Prepend("LogTime")))
        .ToArray();
```

That gives:

```
LogTime;V1;V2;V3;V4;V5
2022/05/31 14:04:00;1.1;2.1;3.1;4.1;5.1
2022/05/31 14:04:10;1.2;2.2;3.2;4.2;5.2
2022/05/31 14:04:20;1.3;2.3;3.3;4.3;5.3
```

Comment: Where does `.StartWith()` come from?

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Sorry, it's from Microsoft's Interactive Extensions library. I changed to `Prepend` which comes out of the box now.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The code is working as expected with Prepend. I am going to run the performance test to see how much improvement in performance. Thank you for the support.

Comment: @JimYu - You're really unlikely to get a performance improvement unless your existing code is horrific. Having said that, `String.Join` is quite efficient in the framework. I look forward to hearing your results.